# Reducer not returning updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, spread-syntax

I can't get my reducer to return updated state.

The action (confirmed with debugger) is an array of objects - something like: `[{name: "test"}, {name: "second_test"}]`

I think something must be wrong with my spread operator, although I've also tried `Object.assign()` in the debugger and that seems to return the expected result.

My components is apparently just getting the default state. Here's my reducer code. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
const initialState = {
    current: {},
    all: []
}

export default function deckReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'CREATE_DECK':
            return {...state, all: [...state.all, action.payload]}

        case 'FETCH_DECKS':

            debugger;
            return {...state, all: action.payload}

        default: return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this very issue recently (exactly as you describe), and I resolved the problem by using the [`immutability-helper`](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) package which is listed [here on the ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html).

This approach allows you to delegate the heavy lifting of state immutability and nested state updates. You should find this resolves your issue:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const initialState = {
    current: {},
    all: []
}

export default function deckReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch(action.type) {

        case 'CREATE_DECK': {
            /* Add payload to nested state.all list */
            return update(state, { all : { $push : [action.payload] }});
        }

        case 'FETCH_DECKS': {    
            /* Replace state.all with incoming payload */
            return update(state, { all : { $set : action.payload }});
        }

        default: return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dacre. I might have to try that. It seems crazy that this would be necessary though. As far as reducers go, this is about as simple as it can get. Is immutability_helper a seperate package?

Comment: @mossexploding yes I agree - I was looking at a similar reducer of mine for a while and experiencing the exact same thing as you in a side project. Using this package solved the issue for me immediately,  so figured I'd share that experience with you :-) . Yes, `immutability-helper` is a separate package, but I've found it to be very useful in simplifying my reducers